# ToolTips of remaining flags and close votes

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, close-dialog, flag-dialog

The ToolTip of the remaining flags in the FlagDialog displays `flags remaining today, UTC`

The **, UTC** is in this case unnecessary and can be removed.

The ToolTip of the CloseDialog is **nearly** correct and displays `vote remaining today`. Theres a missing **s** and it should be `votes remaining today`

[image]

Comment: Considering the huge amount of people who get this wrong the UTC is certainly needed. We have it easy in Europe, fitting in with the sites timezone but not everyone else does.

Comment: For the second feature request regarding that "S" read this tweet: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @hims056 thanks for the tweet. i know it. theres a huge S coming over the hills. better i run

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards i think you know it better than me, since you are from London. If its the case, then UTC is missing in the other ToolTip. I leave the question as it is, cause its really a minor issue.